# Minimum characters per word when evaluating keyword density

Tags: search-engines, keywords

I'm trying to please as many robots (particularly AdSense) as possible by keeping my keywords in check on my website and I've been using keyword density checkers as well, and I'm not sure what the official minimum number of characters that should be used in a word when it is to be checked for keyword density.

If I run my website through a keyword density checker with setting 2 characters per word as minimum word length, then I'll get words like "st", "nd", "rd", and "th" ranking high which on my site is natural because I talk about a date a lot (such as "December 3rd"). I don't split the "st", "nd", "rd" or "th" from the number in the day.

So from search engines perspective, how many characters minimum are required to be together (without space in-between) to qualify it as a word when evaluating it as a keyword in a site when measuring keyword density?

Comment: Terms 2 characters and less are ignored. Not sure that answers your question. But that is the Google bottom line according to what I have read.

Answer (score 1):

[closetnoc](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/36029/closetnoc) says:  "Terms 2 characters and less are ignored. Not sure that answers your question. But that is the Google bottom line according to what I have read."

I'm a bit skeptical that you will ever be able to optimize anything with keyword density.  As long as you use the keywords on the pages and they read naturally, you shouldn't have a problem.    There doesn't seem to be correlation between keyword density and rankings.   I've looked into it and I've seen articles where others have looked into it.  It just doesn't seem to be a factor.

Even for AdSense, using keywords in prominent places (title and headings) seems to do a great job of getting ads targeted correctly.  You shouldn't have to pay attention to keyword density.